# Operation that is opened to REST consumers only

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap

Is there any way to restrict Operation to only available to REST consumers and not to SOAP consumers?

For example:

```
[OperationContract]
List<Response> GetResponses(int orderID);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{orderID}/responses",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<Response> GetResponses(string orderID);
```

While REST consumers can only tackle second method, SOAP consumers see both methods, but in any case they should use first method. So I want to show first method to SOAP consumers only and second to REST consumers only. Can I achieve my goal without creating new service?

Comment: maybe you can't do this

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. That's why I am here ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to separate contracts, one for the SOAP exposed, second for the REST exposed, and then make your service implement both :

**SOAP contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDummySoap
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Response> GetResponses(int orderID);
}
```

**REST contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDummyRest 
{    
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{orderID}/responses",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<Response> GetResponses(string orderID);
}
```

**Service implementation**

```
public class DummyService : IDummySoap, IDummyRest
{
    public List<Response> GetResponses(int orderID)
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    public List<Response> GetResponses(string orderID)
    {
        // Implementation
    }    
}
```

Then those who want to call your service by SOAP will use the SOAP contract and the others the REST contract.

Comment: Oh, great. I just forgot about interfaces. Thanks!